# What is the probability of a three-body collision for a thousand particles Gaussianly sampled and trapped in a harmonic potential?

Tags: collision, probability

I know, the title is confusing because it's put probably badly .

Here is the scenario:

A thousand particles each with initial conditions $(x_0,p_0)$ such that $x_0$ and $p_0$ are sampled from two independent gaussians with zero mean and unity deviation are placed in a harmonic trap of known frequency (say, $\omega=1$) such that their motions are governed by equations: $$x(t)=x_o\cos t+p_o\sin t$$
$$p(t)=p_o\cos t-x_o\sin t$$

I am trying to find the probabilty of at least three particles coinciding (having same exact position) at least once in some very large time $T$ for the randomly chosen initial conditions from a gaussian distribution.

Comment: This looks to be a pretty straightforward problem of statistics in one dimension.  You might start out by noticing that the probability  of 2 (or 3) particles overlapping at $t = 0$.  is zero unless your particles have finite size (length).   Then calculate the probability that any three particles' travel ranges overlap at all.  ( I don't think the second equation is of any use at all here.  )   Since they are all oscillating **in phase** the collision point as a function of $x_0$ and $p_0$ should be pretty straightforward

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Where does the fact of having a gaussian sampled initial conditions come into picture?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Also, I am not really sure what you mean by "calculate the probability that any three particles' travel ranges overlap at all". Wouldn't I have to plug the initial condns to check this?

Comment: yes, you generate random $p_0$ and random $x_0$  and that will give you the extreme range $x_{min} x_{max}$   Only those which  produce triple overlap could possibly have 3-way collisions.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft But there are a thousand particles. How do I possibly do this for all of them? Also, by a triple overlap of trajectories do you mean a common intersection of three trajectories? In any case, I do not have the mental prowess to understand what you *exactly* mean in the few words you have provided.